# How would a god entertain themselves in the long run

Tags: psychology, gods

I have a character who became god, which means they can do anything and bend space and time to their will. They can create new universes or even reset the timeline of an universe and change history forever. The only limit is their imagination.

But how do they avoid dying of boredom? With infinite powers comes a really boring life.

They could make myself a millionaire, but why? If they wanted to buy something they could just create it for free. They could spend a lifetime making the world perfect, but then? What else do they have to do?

It's kind of like those people who become millionaires because they won some prizes and they kill themselves because they don't know what to do with their lives.

So, how do they keep themselves entertained forever without without running out of things to do? They can do everything I can imagine, but eventually my imagination would run out.... Maybe they can do everything, and I mean literary **everything** 2 or 3 times in a row but eventually it would get boring...like watching always the same movie.

They're a god, they don't want to be bored, they want to always have something to do, to see, to listen, to feel...

How can they best accomplish entertainment with a finite amount of things to do with their personal imagination?

Comment: If there's anything that *Arc of a Scythe* and Bowerick Wowbagger the Infinitely Prolonged have taught us, it's that naturally mortal people who become immortal will inevitably become bored; there's nothing you can do to avert it.

Comment: This question is the epitome of “opinion based” questions. Literally any answer is possible (because omnipotent) and rightness depends on the individual what is considered not boring. Voting to close. And voting to add this to the help as an example of “opinion based question”.

Comment: And God said, let me be not bored. And God was not bored, and God saw that it was good.

Comment: thats why they create [human](https://thequotes.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Chuck-Palahniuk-Quotes-3.jpg)

Comment: I am trying to understand why is this question closed?
"opinion based" in worldbuilding?
Can someone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can do everything then you should be able to use your powers and magically make yourself excited for everything.

Comment: Or continually wipe your memories. Maybe plant your consciousness (or a fraction thereof) into a mortal's mind and erase your knowledge that you're actually an all-powerful god.

Answer (score 0):

You create a world with infinite potential meaning and advance an animal specie so it becomes self-aware.